# CSS display none on hover for different divs

Tags: css, hover

I set up an page with multiple divs, and I want to make it so that when you hover on one div, the other divs disappear. I tried to use this:

```css
.Features:hover ~ .Short .Digital {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Features">
  <h3>Features</h3>
  <ul class="1">
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>Do, rey, mi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="Short">
  <h3>Short Reviews</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>Do, rey, mi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="Digital">
  <h3>Digital Reviews</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>Do, rey, mi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but nothing happens. I also tried to change the opacity of the div, but that didn't work either. Can anyone help?

Comment: [`,` is a grouping selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping): http://jsfiddle.net/omrL84wm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close.  You just needed to group together some of your css properly.  Try the following snippet to see a working example:

```css
.Features:hover ~ .Short, .Features:hover ~ .Digital {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Features">
  <h3>Features</h3>
  <ul class="1">
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>Do, rey, mi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="Short">
  <h3>Short Reviews</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>Do, rey, mi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="Digital">
  <h3>Digital Reviews</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>Do, rey, mi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Is there also a way to run it backwards, i.e. hide .Features when I hover over .Digital or .Short? I tried running that too and for some reason it only hides the divs that are placed below it in the HTML doc.

Comment: @HannahBanana - The "general sibling selector" (~) only works one direction: .a ~.b means a .b element must follow an .a element.  You cannot use this syntax to go backwards.  More information on general sibling selectors can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

Comment: @HannahBanana - CSS does not allow you to move up in the DOM, unfortunately (so, no `:parent()` or `:ancestor`). So you can only move laterally or downwards.

Answer (score 2):

What you currently are doing is the following:

```
.Features:hover  -- On Hover element
~                -- Find sibblings
.Short .Digital  -- With class .Short and then an item inside somewhere .Digital
```

What you need is:

```
.Features:hover ~ div
```

or

```
.Features:hover ~ .Short, .Features:hover ~ .Digital
```

So find siblings which have a class `Short` or `Digital`.

Comment: I tried fixing that, but unfortunately it still won't work :/ I even tried just taking off the .Digital to see if it would just hide .Short and it doesn't affect at all.

Comment: Oh never mind I realized my mistake. I simplified the html when I pasted it into here, and I realize in the source doc that .Short and .Digital are inside of another div. Is there a way to select them even though they aren't siblings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `,` between two divs. JSFiddle link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p2tmLaq9/)